# What are the size limitations of Databin & CloudPut?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, databin

I'm trying to add a symbol (whose ByteCount is 181 megabytes) to a new empty databin I created, but it fails:

[image]

Wondering about the size limitations of values in a Databin?

Comment: It could also be a timeout issue. I know lots of cloud stuff throws timeouts if the request takes more than like 5-15 seconds or something.

Answer (score 5):

So I think that is most likely a timeout issue as this is what you get if you try to add something too large:

[image]

I got your message for anything that took more than 5 or so seconds.

Comment: So 25 kilobytes is the max per item in a databin?

Comment: That might be a per entry limit as I'm pretty sure I have databins with more stuff in them than that.

Comment: CloudPut and CloudGet seem to have higher limits

Comment: Yeah, I've pushed ~35 MB into a `CloudExpression` before.

Comment: Does it depend on a cloud subscription?

Comment: If you mean the size limit, I have no idea. If you mean can you use `CloudExpression` sans cloud subscription, then the answer is yes.